# Is there a way in Google Sheets to lock a row from sorting, but, not be frozen?

Tags: google-sheets

I want to have a few rows at the top of a list, that are not part of the "header/titles" row (which is frozen), but, I always want it on top. If someone does a quick sort by column, I want those to stay in rows 2-4, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Select the sort range to start at Row5.